# beforeunload event on component which created by map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onbeforeunload

hello everyone im trying to send request to backend while closing the browser. I have a simple code.

Parent:

```
/*codes*/

return(
<>
{items.map(item => <div key={item.key}>
<Child item={item} />
</div>)}
</>
);
```

Child

```
    /*codes*/
    
        useEffect(() => {
        const handleWindowClose= () => {
          post(props.item.id,props.item.status)
        };
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleWindowClose);
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleWindowClose);
        };
      }, []);
/*more codes*/
```

but it seems that only 1 element sending request others cant.

how to fix this ?
maybe an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the child components are using the same event listener callback function.

You need to modify the event listener callback function specifying the item:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleWindowClose = () => {
    post(props.item.id, props.item.status);
  };

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleWindowClose);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleWindowClose);
  };
}, [props.item.id, props.item.status]); //add item properties
```